# Ajax load some html in Jcarousel?

Tags: ajax, javascript

Though I am able to add items via ajax into a drupal jcarousel, the new items are not being registered and lack the `jcarouselindex="N"`  I've tried `jQuery(target).reload` but no luck.

Does anyone know what I need to do to get them recognised as new items in jcarousel? Here is the code in **node-type.tpl.php**:

```
<?php
jcarousel_add('.audioforumtable',
  array('vertical' => false, 'skin' => tango,'scroll' => 1)
);
?>
```

And here is the javascript:

```
Drupal.behaviors.ajaxlinks = function (context) {

    jQuery('.audioforumtable').jcarousel;

$('.morelink:not(.togg-processed)', context).addClass('togg-processed').each(function () {
    $(this).click(function() {
    var target = $('.newthing');
    var toLoad = Drupal.settings.basePath + 'replies/' + mynid;
          xhr = $.ajax({
          url: toLoad,
          success: function(data) {
    $(target).html($(data));
    jQuery('.audioforumtable').reload();
    Drupal.attachBehaviors(target);}
  });
});
}
```

Comment: I may be a little rusty, but why not `$(target).html(data);`?

Comment: Thanks, but it has not made any difference.